# How to inherit javascript in odoo 12

Tags: odoo

I need to inherit the whole code of data_export.js file into my_js_file to remove certain codes.

Is it possible!?

Comment: Refer to the Odoo [Patching an existing class](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/fr/developer/reference/javascript_reference.html#patching-an-existing-class) documentation. If it is not already done, your script should be added to the `assets_bundle`. For more details,  check [Adding files in an asset bundle](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/fr/developer/reference/javascript_reference.html#adding-files-in-an-asset-bundle) section.